# How to call a function that is bound to key press only once

Tags: python

I am making a game and what I am trying to do is when moving the character around check if the character location is close to any object location, at which point i want to trigger my dialogue window to pop up.  The problem I am having is that since the "checking if character location is close to object location" is binded to my key_press, it runs this a thousand times and calls the function multiple times when holding the key down.  I am unable to come up with a solution to this.  What I tried to do was add a counter outside the function and then add to it when the function is called and say if the counter is < 2 then proceed. Also, I'm not even sure if the actual code to check if the widget locations are near each other is correct.

The code in question is all the way at the bottom 'for i in listofwidgets':

```
class MoveableImage(Image):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MoveableImage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(None, self)
        if not self._keyboard:
            return
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self.on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_up=self.on_keyboard_up)

        self.y = (Window.height/2.1)
        self.app = App.get_running_app()

    def on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):

        if keycode[1] == 'left':
            self.source = 'selectionscreen/left.zip'

        if self.x < (Window.width * .25):
            if any(self.collide_widget(i) for i in listofwidgets):
                bglayout.x +=0
            else:
                bglayout.x += 4
            else:
                if any(self.collide_widget(i) for i in listofwidgets):
                    self.x -=0
                else:
                    self.x -=6
        for i in listofwidget:
            if i.x - self.x < 10:  #if image x location and self x location are within 100 pixels 
            calldialoguebox()

counter=0
def calldialoguebox(*args):
    counter+=1
        if counter < 2:
            Clock.schedule_interval(typenewmessage.example, .5) #types message in dialogue box word by word every interval
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: What type of event are you capturing ? Key_press ? Key_down ? Key_up ? If you're using key_pressed that's your problem, because it's called many times, you could use key_down, that is called just once per key pressed. Could you show the main boucle ? the line where you capture key events ? [Here you have examples](http://pygametutorials.wikidot.com/tutorials-three)

Comment: key_down.  I understand that is my problem, but I was wondering how to work around it.  I need key_down as that is how my character moves.

Comment: Could you show your event handler ? how you capture key_down ?

Comment: is `def calldialoguebox` in the same class as `def on_keyboard_down` ?

Comment: calldialoguebox is not in the same class as on_keyboard_down

Comment: i have updated the code to show the entire class.